# Why didn't I get rep for upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation

I got two upvotes on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/485790/download-a-file-from-the-shell-when-button-click-is-required) but no rep from them. I was nowhere near the rep cap for the day, and I can't think of any other reason I wouldn't get the rep.

Why wouldn't I get rep for those upvotes?

(Note I'm sure it's calculated correctly, I'm just curious why they didn't count)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Triggering a Rep Recalc by clicking the button at the bottom of https://serverfault.com/reputation

Comment: Looks like that gave me the missing 20 rep.  It doesn't show up beside the upvotes when I go to my profile's reputation tab, but the rep did increase.  Probably that page is just cached/takes awhile to update.  Thank you.

Comment: Your User Profile page is cached for up to 30 minutes. Weird fluke... It probably happens a lot, but there are automatic rep-recalcs weekly or so. I'm sure most wouldn't notice.

Comment: I simply would not even care - it's just rep, it's not like it is going to turn into gold one day...